# how to prevent sanctum from defining its routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

after installing laravel/sanctum it will define a **"GET"** route with "**sanctum/csrf-cookie"** address.
it happens by running **defineRoutes()** function in **"**vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\SanctumServiceProvider.php**"**
how can i prevent this from happening or remove mentioned route ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `defineRoutes` method of the service provider, you will see the following:

```
if ($this->app->routesAreCached() || config('sanctum.routes') === false) {
    return;
}
```

This means, you can publish Sanctum's config and add a key `'routes' => false,` to it to disable the routes from being loaded.

So publish the config file like:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"
```

Then add the `'routes' => false,` to the file, and make sure if you are caching your config to refresh the cache.